# Integrating sharepoint 2013 with Microsoft CRM users

Tags: dynamics-crm, sharepoint-integration

How can I integrate sharepoint 2013 with Microsoft CRM so when users login one of then can go to another one?
I want users to register in one of them and be able to login on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has already provided step by step solution to integrate Microsoft Dynamics CRM & SharePoint.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/anand_nigam/archive/2011/12/04/crm-2011-and-sharepoint-2010-integration-part-1.aspx

Comment: Is there any 3rd party tools I can use to integrate dynamic CRM and SharePoint?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options for building federation trust solutions between two identity providers (SharePoint & Dynamics CRM). I'm assuming they are commonly Windows Server Active Directory.

- Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS)
- Two-way trust on domain controller
- Custom SAML-based claim authentication identity provider